# Problems with formatting a date in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I am implementing the Bootstrap Date Range Picker on my Symfony CRM, in order for my client to choose a range of dates for a particular holiday season.

However, when it comes to adding the data to the database, it needs to be in the format of Start Date and End Date. The database expects a `DateTime` object, but I want it to be more readable on the front end for the client.

This is what gets passed back to the Controller once submitted:

> 20/5/2017 - 20/7/2017

In my Controller, I use the following code:

```
$dates = $form['startDate']->getData();
$date_bits = explode(" - ",$dates);
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date_bits[0]);
$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$date_bits[1]);
```

Except when I persist to the database I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in
>   /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php on line
>   53

So I tried this method instead:

```
$startDate = new \DateTime(str_replace("/","-",$date_bits[0]));
$endDate = new \DateTime(str_replace("/","-",$date_bits[1]));
$startDate = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = $endDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

But I receive the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: Actually for the second code block, the error states I am calling `format()` on a string.

Comment: What's wrong with `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y')`? Read about the [date & time formats understood by `strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: It needs to go into the database like `Y-m-d` as that is what the date field expects.

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_bits[0])->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime::createFromFormat() returning false means that whatever string representing the date you're submitting to it does not match the format you have provided.

The first parameter of DateTime::createFromFormat should be the format that you are submitting to it, in this case "d/m/Y". You can then do $startDate->format('Y-m-d') to get the date formatted the way you want it.

```
$dates = $form['startDate']->getData();
$date_bits = explode(" - ",$dates);
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$date_bits[0])->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-05-20
$endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$date_bits[1])->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-07-20
```

NB: Don't use->format() if you want it to remain as a DateTime object. Format always returns a string.

Comment: Are you sure that your $dates is actually a string of '20/5/2017 - 20/7/2017'? I just tested the above code myself and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes it worked - sorry, I was playing around in PHP Sandbox and had changed the format temporarily! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Usually with date I'm using this:

```
$startDate = new \Datetime($date_bits[0]);
$endDate = new \Datetime($date_bits[1]);
```

if you want to use CreateFromFormat try this please:

```
$startDate = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_bits[0])->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date_bits[1])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error. Here is the print of `$date_bits`: `Array ( [0] => 01/02/2017 [1] => 30/04/2017 )`

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php on line 53

is generated by code that attempts to call [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) on something that is not a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) object but a boolean (`FALSE`, to be more specific).

It is actually the value of `$startDate`, returned by `DateTime::__construct()` that doesn't know how to parse your input string.

You pass it a date like `20/5/2017`. Obviously, its format is `'d/m/Y'`.

[`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) do not understand it. They expect either `m/d/Y` or `Y/m/d`. It is impossible for them to tell apart `d/m/Y` from `m/d/Y` without any hint and the PHP programmers have chosen to ignore `d/m/Y` because `m/d/Y` is used more.

However, for date & time formats not understood directly, there always exists the function [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It allows you to tell the engine what date & time components to search for into the string and in which order.

All you have to do is to use it properly:

```
$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$date_bits[0]);
```